# Change gradle's local repo cache location for Jenkins cloud build

Tags: maven, groovy, gradle

I need to change where repo downloads are saved. I cannot use the user home because my build is run on a cloud service which does not preserve this.

This is causing my deps to be downloaded over and over and is chewing up a lot of cloud buld time.

I am using gradle 1.0 milestone 5 and my build file has the following repos setup:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenRepo urls: ['http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/', 'http://test-utils.googlecode.com/svn/maven-repo/snapshots']
    flatDir(name: 'fileRepo', dirs: "$projectDir/libs")
}
```

(I have changed test-utils to hide some test lib I'm messing with).

I have added this execute sh step before gradle build:

```
env GRADLE_USER_HOME="${WORKSPACE}"
export GRADLE_USER_HOME="${WORKSPACE}"
```

But the deps must be being downloaded elsewhere still because my Jenkins build's workspace does not have any downloaded deps in it, but it does have some temp gradle files in it.

Any ideas how I can make sure downloaded deps are placed in the $WORKSPACE so that I can avoid these downloads all the time?

Comment: Sure they're not in a folder `${WORKSPACE}/.gradle`?

Comment: There are gradle things in there but there was no cache.

Comment: Not really related to your problem, but that `env` line does not do what you want it to do and is redundant.

Comment: environment vars are not preserved through different build steps in Jenkins. So if you `echo $GRADLE_USER_HOME` in shell-script build step next to yours, you'll see nothing. But there are some jenkins plugins to do that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Defining `GRADLE_USER_HOME` should do the trick.

Setting `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to `${WORKSPACE}` will put various directories under `${WORKSPACE}`. I'd create `${WORKSPACE}/gradle-home` and set `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to that.

Check what `${WORKSPACE}` resolves to.

You can also try setting the gradle user home directory using the `-g` command line option.

Comment: Solved by setting up environment var plugin in jenkins. Your answer is correct outside of that.